Не могу сделать закругленный Canvas для картинки в Tkinter
properties_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "build", "images", "builder_images", "base", "Rectangle.png")
        
self.image_properties = Image.open(properties_path)
self.resize_properties_image = self.image_properties.resize((3000, 1750), Image.LANCZOS)
self.load_image_properties = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resize_properties_image)
        
self.canvas_properties = tk.Canvas(self, bg="#696969", highlightthickness=0)
self.canvas_properties.place(relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.8, relx=0.2, rely=0.05)
self.canvas_properties.create_image(0, 0, image=self.load_image_properties)

как к этому canvas добавить закругленные края? Нигде не нашел туториала как это сделать

Насколько мне известно, может я и ошибаюсь, закруглённость углов виджетов "не Питона дело". Насколько виджеты будут похожи на большинство объектов в Windows больше зависит от собственно линейки Windows. В школьном варианте (tkinter, ttk) наибольшей похожести можно добиться с помощью стилизации виджетов ttk. Но Canvas в это подмножество не входит.

Закругленный Canvas нельзя сделать. Можно сделать картинку с закругленными краями.
